# Issue On Adding Class to Specific <td> with a Class

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/poz1f1a3/) and let me know why I am not able to add `.sale` class to last columns of table which has a class of `.item` using `.find()`

```
$(function () {
    $('td:nth-child(6) ,td:nth-child(7)').find("item").addClass("sale");
});
```

Comment: `item` should `.item` and remove `!important` from your css rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a dot in item. It should be

```
$(function () {
    $('td:nth-child(6) ,td:nth-child(7)').find(".item").addClass("sale");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/poz1f1a3/2/

The css

```
.item {
    background-color: grey;
    height:45px;
    width:65px;
}
.sale {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: @user3649067 It works :) Check the fiddle :) Don't write !important, and read a little bit about css rules, in what order styles are applied :)

Comment: I was getting ready to say that you have to reverse the order of the CSS classes.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that the order of CSS is that important!